# Scrollify Move not working when sectionName is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-scrollify

I am using Scrollify plugin. I want to Move to a section when I click a button. But when I set `sectionName` to `false`, it doesn't seem to work. It works fine when `sectionName` isn't set to `false`, but I don't want to see # on my address bar because when I refresh/reload the page (on the 3rd section for example) and scrolls, it scrolls rigth away to the next section (from 1st section to 4th). 
 Is there a way to **MOVE** to a particular section when `sectionName` is `false`?

Here's what I did so far:

 **JS**

```
$('.goNotify').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.scrollify.move($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#notify" class="goNotify">
    <button id="btnDrive" class="btnNotif" type="button" name="btnDrive" title="Get Notified When Available">Get Notified When Available</button>
</a>

<section id="notify" class="panel" data-section-name="notify">
<!-- content -->
</section>
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the index of the section you want to move to to the move method.

Comment: I am stuck with this same issue.  with the same scenario and similar code .not working for me . can you help me to come out with this  ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, so I had the same problem and bypass it by this piece of code :

```
$("a.scrollify").on("click",function() {
    $.scrollify.move( getScrollifySectionIndex( $(this).attr("href") ) );
});
```

The « **getScrollifySectionIndex** » method parse the href and return the panel index :

```
function getScrollifySectionIndex(anchor){
    var idpanel = false;
    jQuery('section.panel').each(function(i){
        if( jQuery(this).data('section-name') == anchor.toString().replace(/#/g,"") ){
        //console.log( jQuery(this).data('section-name') , i , anchor.toString().replace(/#/g,"") );
        idpanel = i;
        }
    });
    return idpanel;
};
```

It works very fine :)